# Angular Isolated scope not binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive created as follow and controller below, but I can seems to get the parent scope working

```js
"use strict";
app.directive("ccDetails", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "/give/creditcarddetails",
        scope: {
            showCreditCardDetails: "=showCreditCardDetails",
            creditCardDetails: "=",
            nameOnCard: "="
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log("Name on card is " + $scope.nameOnCard);
            console.log("showCreditCardDetails is " + $scope.showCreditCardDetails);
            console.log("creditCardDetails is " + $scope.creditCardDetails);
        }
    }
});
```

and I am dynamically compiling and appending it to part of my DOM.

```js
"use strict";
app.controller("giveController", [
    "$scope", "$compile", function ($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.donationTypes = [
            { id: 1, name: "Credit Card" }
        ];

        $scope.donationTypeChange = function () {

            
            $scope.showCreditCardDetails = false;
            $scope.nameOnCard = "James";

            // credit card donationType
            if ($scope.selectedDonationType != null && $scope.selectedDonationType.id === 1) {
                var creditCardDetailsHtml = $compile("<cc-Details showCreditCardDetails=\"showCreditCardDetails\"></cc-Details>")($scope);
             
                $scope.showCreditCardDetails = true;
                console.log(creditCardDetailsHtml);

               $(".give-step-1").after(creditCardDetailsHtml);
               
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

The scope is not binding and is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute on the HTML needs to be with dashes instead of camel case. Also the directive's name itself:

```
"<cc-details show-credit-card-details=\"showCreditCardDetails\"></cc-details>"
```

Regarding the other attributes, since your directive has an isolated scope, you need to pass all objects you want through the HTML element.

Comment: Except maybe it should be a lowercase "d": `<cc-details>`

Comment: or use a service to pass additional data